# Bluetooth Speaker battery

Tags: bluetooth, battery, bluetooth-speaker

How do I check the battery for my bluetooth speaker. I tried solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49078659/check-battery-level-of-connected-bluetooth-device-on-linux. But none of them work in 2020.

I also tried https://github.com/TheWeirdDev/Bluetooth_Headset_Battery_Level. But it wont work. I get an error `F4:4E:FD:34:7D:59 is offline [Errno 111] Connection refused`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am also currently using a script utilizing the mentioned GitHub project polling and showing on my taskbar the battery level.
Something like:

```bsh
BATTERY_STATUS=$(bluetooth_battery $(bluetoothctl devices | grep HS70 | awk '{print $2}') | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d'%' -f1)
```

And then I print the battery level of my device `HS70`.
Sometimes it works, some times it fails and I have to turn off and on again the bluetooth or switch between `High Fidelity Playback` and `Headset Unit`.
I haven't managed to find a better solution for this one.
`upower -e` or `upower --dump` ain't working either.
I believe that the problem comes from the way the driver works due to the fact that my headset comes with 2 interfaces (one for music playback and one for sound and microphone).